# 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'addElem' of undefined' on a button click in React JS using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

trying to create a simple calculator using ReactJS and Redux. Added a input box, and some buttons(for numbers 0-9) below it so that, when clicked on the button, the input box value is to be updated with the button value. when clicked on the equal(=) button, the input string should be evaluated and the input box to be updated with the result value. Unable to figure out how to send the data on button click to the input box. Below is the code:

container:

```
import React from 'react';
import Calculator from '../components/Calculator'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import store from '../store'

class CalcLogic extends React.Component{


    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="row" > Calculator </div> <br/>
                <div className="row text-center" >
                 <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value={this.props.value} /> 
                </div>  <br/>
                <div className="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4" style={{backgroundColor:'lightGrey' }} > 
                <div className="row "> 

                {
                    this.props.btns.map((item,key) =>{
                    return <Calculator key={key} item={item} value={this.props.value} />
                    })
                }
                </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return{
        value: state.value,
         btns: state.btns
      }
  }


  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CalcLogic);
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionsCreator, bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
import {addElem,clear,equals} from '../actions/actions'


const Calculator=(props) => {

     return(
        <div className="container text-center" > <br/>
                {
                props.item == "clear"? <button className="btn btn-small btn-default col-md-3" key={props.key}
                onClick={()=> {this.props.clear}} > {props.item} </button> : props.item == "="?<button className="btn btn-small btn-default col-md-3" key={props.key}
                onClick={()=> {this.props.equals(props.value)}} > {props.item} </button>:<button className="btn btn-small btn-default col-md-3" key={props.key}
                onClick={()=> {this.props.addElem(props.item)}} > {props.item} </button>
                }
        </div>
        );  
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      addElem: (text) =>{
            dispatch(addElem(text));
      },
        clear: () =>{
          dispatch(clear());
      } ,
      equals: (value) =>{
          dispatch(equals(value));
      } 
  };
};      


 export default connect(() => {return {}; } , mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator);
```

Reducer:

```
    const calcState = {
        value: 0,
        btns: [ "clear", "=", "0", "/", "7", "8", "9", "*", "4", "5", "6", "+", "1", "2", "3", "-"]
    }

const Reducer= (state = calcState,
        action) => {
switch(action.type){

    case 'ADDELEM':
           return{
                   ...state,
                   value: state.value == '0' ? action.payload : state.value + action.payload
           }
    case 'CLEAR':
            return{
                    ...state,
                    value:0
           }
     case 'EQUALS':
            return{
                    ...state,
                    value:eval(action.payload)
            }
            default: return state;
}
}

export default Reducer;
```

actions:

```
 const addElem=(text)=> {
     return{
         type:'ADDELEM',
         payload:text
     };
 },

  clear=()=>{
    return{
        type:'CLEAR' 
    };
},

 equals=(value)=> {
    return{
        type:'EQUALS',
        payload:value
    };
}

export {addElem,clear,equals};
```

Comment: In calculator component do replace `this.props` with `props`

Comment: Hey, its working now. Thanks alot ! But, why cant i use this.props.addElem()? we use mapDispatchToProps() so that the component can use it as props right?

Comment: You're using functional component, not the class component. In functional components you get props as function parameters whereas in class components you get them as instance properties. functional components are light weight and dont have access to lifecycle methods.

Comment: got it. thanks again :)